# Off screen Rendering With Multisampling

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I am drawing a quad and adding texture to it and drawing small quad and adding textures. When the sample count is 4 I got following error when small quad is added. when the sample count is one is it is working fine.

```
Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Ignored (for causing prior/excessive GPU errors) (IOAF code 4)
```

How can i use sample count 4

```
guard let drawable = view.currentDrawable else { return }

let textureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor()

textureDescriptor.textureType = MTLTextureType.type2DMultisample
textureDescriptor.width = drawable.texture.width
textureDescriptor.height = drawable.texture.height
textureDescriptor.pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
textureDescriptor.storageMode = .shared
 textureDescriptor.sampleCount = 4

textureDescriptor.usage = [.renderTarget, .shaderRead]
let sampleTexture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: textureDescriptor)


let renderPass = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
renderPass.colorAttachments[0].texture = sampleTexture
renderPass.colorAttachments[0].resolveTexture = outTexture
renderPass.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .clear
renderPass.colorAttachments[0].clearColor =
    MTLClearColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
 renderPass.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .multisampleResolve

let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()

let semaphore = inFlightSemaphore

commandBuffer?.addCompletedHandler { (_ commandBuffer)-> Swift.Void in
        semaphore.signal()
}

var commandEncoder = commandBuffer?.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPass)

for scene in scenes {
    scene.render(commandEncoder: commandEncoder!)
}

commandEncoder?.endEncoding()


let descriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor
commandEncoder = commandBuffer?.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: descriptor!)



for x in canvasScenes{
    x.updateCanvas(texture: sampleTexture!)
    x.render(commandEncoder: commandEncoder!)
}

commandEncoder?.endEncoding()


commandBuffer?.present(drawable)
commandBuffer?.commit()
commandBuffer?.waitUntilCompleted()
```

Comment: If you're drawing with MSAA (i.e., your render pipeline state has `sampleCount` > 0), the following things must be the case: (1) your render pass descriptor color attachment(s) must have a `resolveTexture` of type `type2D` set; (2) the texture set as the `texture` of the color attachment(s) must be of type `.type2DMultisample`; and (3) its `sampleCount` must match that of the render pipeline state. As far as I can see, none of these is true in the code you posted, though this should have been caught by the validation layer. (Are you running with validation enabled?)

Comment: Metal Validation I disabled. When disabled I can draw one quad Error comes in Second Quad drawing. Yh If validation enabled Error comes

Comment: @warrenm I made textureDescriptors texture type to type 2D Multisample , sample count 4 and resolve texture to a outTexture a variable of Type MTLTexture , and renderpass descriptors store action to multisample resolve when I do that I receive following error message

Comment: failed assertion `MTLRenderPassDescriptor MTLStoreActionMultisampleResolve store action requires resolve texture'

Comment: textureDescriptor.textureType = MTLTextureType.type2DMultisample .                     textureDescriptor.sampleCount = 4
renderPass.colorAttachments[0].resolveTexture = outTexture .  renderPass.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .multisampleResolve .                 these are the changes I made in above code and receive the above error messgae

Comment: Edit your question to show your new code and errors. Don't put it in comments. **Always** run with validation enabled, except when testing performance. Fix any issues that the validation layer finds. Don't ignore them.

Comment: @warrenm I editted Now I got the error mentioned above

Comment: @KenThomases Editted

Comment: `sampleTexture` doesn't need to have `.shaderRead` in its usage flags; you're never sampling from it. That's more of an optimization tip, though; it probably isn't causing your IOAF errors. Usually, IOAF code 4 isn't the first error to appear (it indicates your app has been blacklisted for causing too many other errors). Are there other IOAF logs further up?

Comment: @warrenm I got following Error not IOAF error  "   failed assertion `MTLRenderPassDescriptor resolveTexture must not be MTLTextureType2DMultisample.'  "" after changing usage to renderTarget

Comment: resolveTexture.textureType = .type2D
texture.textureType = .type2DMultisample

if you have depth texture 
depthTexture.textureType =  .type2DMultisample

resolve texture SHOULD NOT have resolve usage .renderTarget, only .sharedWrite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's my setup for offscreen rendering with multisampling. I use also depth texture. Here is written small description about multisampling https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlrenderpassattachmentdescriptor?language=objc

```
    let offscreenTextureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor()
    offscreenTextureDescriptor.width = size.width
    offscreenTextureDescriptor.height = size.height
    offscreenTextureDescriptor.depth = size.depth
    offscreenTextureDescriptor.pixelFormat = RenderPixelFormat.offscreen.rawValue.mtlPixelFormat()
    offscreenTextureDescriptor.textureType = .type2DMultisample
    offscreenTextureDescriptor.storageMode = .shared
    offscreenTextureDescriptor.usage = [.renderTarget, .shaderRead, .shaderWrite, .pixelFormatView]
    offscreenTextureDescriptor.sampleCount = 4

    self.offScreenTexture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: offscreenTextureDescriptor)

    offscreenTextureDescriptor.textureType = .type2D
    offscreenTextureDescriptor.sampleCount = 1
    offscreenTextureDescriptor.usage = [.shaderWrite]

    self.resolveOffScreenTexture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: offscreenTextureDescriptor)

    let depthTextureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(pixelFormat: .depth32Float, width: self.offScreenTexture.width, height: self.offScreenTexture.height, mipmapped: false)
    depthTextureDescriptor.usage = [.renderTarget, .shaderRead, .shaderWrite, .pixelFormatView]
    depthTextureDescriptor.textureType = .type2DMultisample
    depthTextureDescriptor.storageMode = .private
    depthTextureDescriptor.resourceOptions = [.storageModePrivate]
    depthTextureDescriptor.sampleCount = 4

    let depthAttachementTexureDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDepthAttachmentDescriptor()
    depthAttachementTexureDescriptor.clearDepth = 1.0
    depthAttachementTexureDescriptor.loadAction = .clear
    depthAttachementTexureDescriptor.storeAction = .store
    depthAttachementTexureDescriptor.texture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: depthTextureDescriptor)

    let renderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = self.offScreenTexture
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].resolveTexture = self.resolveOffScreenTexture
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(0, 0, 0, 1)
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .clear
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .multisampleResolve
    renderPassDescriptor.depthAttachment = depthAttachementTexureDescriptor
    self.renderPassDescriptor = renderPassDescriptor
```